# Regex to match strings in a list without .csv extension

Tags: python, regex

How can i write a regular expression to only match the string names without .csv extension. This should be the required output

```
Required Output:
 ['ap_2010', 'class_size', 'demographics', 'graduation','hs_directory', 'sat_results']

Input:
data_files = [
"ap_2010.csv",
"class_size.csv",
"demographics.csv",
"graduation.csv",
"hs_directory.csv",
"sat_results.csv"]
```

I tried but it return a empty list.

```
for i in data_files:
    regex = re.findall(r'/w+/_[/d{4}][/w*]?', i)
```

Comment: I think regex is overkill. What about `[i[:-4] for i in data_files]`?

Comment: yeah that would work but I just want to do it with Regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use a regular expression, you can use `re.sub` to remove the extension if it exists, and if not, leave the string alone:

```
[re.sub(r'\.csv$', '', i) for i in data_files]

['ap_2010',
 'class_size',
 'demographics',
 'graduation',
 'hs_directory',
 'sat_results']
```

A better approach in general is using the `os` module to handle anything to do with filenames:

```
[os.path.splitext(i)[0] for i in data_files]

['ap_2010',
 'class_size',
 'demographics',
 'graduation',
 'hs_directory',
 'sat_results']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want regex, the solution is `r'(.*)\.csv`:

```
for i in data_files:
    regex = re.findall(r'(.*)\.csv', i)
    print(regex)
```

[image]

Comment: @U9-Forward thanks your suggestion, I will care for it next time.

Answer (score 1):

Split the string at `'.'` and then take the last element of the split (using index `[-1]`). If this is `'csv'` then it is a csv file.

```
for i in data_files:
    if i.split('.')[-1].lower() == 'csv':
        # It is a CSV file
    else:
        # Not a CSV
```

Comment: This will fail on files with more than 1 period and files without an extension.  If the files are guaranteed to have an extension, simply use `rsplit('.', 1)` to avoid the multiple period issue

Answer (score 1):

```
# Input
data_files = [ 'ap_2010.csv', 'class_size.csv', 'demographics.csv', 'graduation.csv', 'hs_directory.csv', 'sat_results.csv' ]

import re

pattern = '(?P<filename>[a-z0-9A-Z_]+)\.csv'
prog = re.compile(pattern)

# `map` function yields:
#  - a `List` in Python 2.x
#  - a `Generator` in Python 3.x
result = map(lambda data_file: re.search(prog, data_file).group('filename'), data_files)
```

Comment: Can you explain the pattern a little bit?

Comment: @sai_636 The pair of parenthesis `(` and `)` defines a group in the pattern. With `?P<filename>`, the group has a name, aka. `filename`; otherwise you have to invoke `group(1)` instead of `group('filename')` in my code. The pair of brackets `[` and `]` defines a range; `[a-z]` matches all English characters in lowercase, `[A-Z]` matches all English characters in uppercase, `[0-9]` matches all digits; thus [a-zA-Z0-9_] matches all English characters, all digits plus underscore `_`. The plus sign `+` means the token immediately before it, aka. `[a-z0-9A-Z_]` shall repeat more than once.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [
"ap_2010.csv",
"class_size.csv",
"demographics.csv",
"graduation.csv",
"hs_directory.csv",
"sat_results.csv"]

print([i.rstrip('.'+i.split('.')[-1]) for i in l])
```